Dynamic role assignment in Azure with Terraform
I want to dynamically create Azure Key Vaults and perform role assignments based on a YAML config file. The format of the YAML file is as follows:
kv1:
  - "user1@email.com"
  - "user2@email.com"
kv1:
  - "user2@email.com"
  - "user3@email.com"

This gives me a Terraform map on the following format:
{
  "kv1" = [
    "user1@email.com",
    "user2@email.com",
  ]
  "kv2" = [
    "user2@email.com",
    "user3@email.com",
  ]
}

So far, I have the following for creating the different key vaults:
locals {
  key_vault_config = yamldecode("${file("../keyvaults.yaml")}")
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = local.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "this" {
  for_each                   = local.key_vault_config
  name                       = each.key
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  enable_rbac_authorization  = true
  ...
}

No I need to somehow dynamically add the correct users to the correct key vaults, using the azuread_user/azuread_users and azurerm_role_assignment, but I am struggling on how I could achieve this. The users should have the role_definition_name = "Key Vault Administrator", for a single key vault/user it would look something like this:
data "azuread_user" "this" {
  user_principal_name = each.value.email
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "this" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.this.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Administrator"
  principal_id         = azuread_user.this.object_id
}

